# Why does my cron job create a log with a trailing question mark?

Tags: linux, php, cron

I have the following cron job:

```
 */5 8-20 * * * php /var/www/user/cron_email.php >> /var/www/log/log.txt
```

It creates the following file:

```
david@ubuntu:/var/www/log$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   540 2011-05-30 17:10 log.txt?
```

Why is it creating a trailing question mark?  How can I stop that?

(I am logging in on the console and seeing the results with no editor so I know that "?" is there.)

And this is the only file that has a trailing '?' so I know its not an editor problem. I am not even using any editor, Im just viewing the console CRT screen.

Comment: How did you add the job to the crontab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running this command will provide more info:

```
$ crontab -l | cat -tve
```

I'm fairly confident you will see extra characters at the end of the output, something like this:

```
*/5 8-20 * * * php /var/www/user/cron_email.php >> /var/www/log/log.txtM-U$
```

the dollar sign just signals end of line (-e option to cat). Anything betwee `.txt` and `$` is extra garbage, probably due to reasons listed in other answers.

The easiest way to fix this is to set your `$EDITOR` to a simple editor and re-edit the crontab.  For example:

```
$ EDITOR=/usr/bin/pico crontab -e
```

then remove any extraneous characters at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Your editor is using CRLF as EOL instead of just LF, and that character is being considered part of the filename. Make sure your editor uses the correct line endings.

Comment: I dont think so, I logged in on the console and I can see that question mark there.

Comment: `ls -q` will show unprintable characters in a filename as `?`. Are you sure it isn't aliased?

Comment: And this is the only file that has a trailing '?' so I know its not an editor problem.  I am not even using any editor, Im just viewing the console CRT screen.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain more please. How to make editor to use LF?

Answer (score 0):

The [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) of `ls` shows that if the command is run inside a terminal, control characters will be displayed as a '?' character instead of the actual control character. In this case, the control character will presumably be an errant line-feed left by your editor instead of the standard UNIX `\n` character.

You need to configure your text editor to use UNIX line-endings (LF), and not use CRLF, or use the 'visudo' command-line editor to alter your cronjobs which will handle this for you automatically.

Comment: I am not using any editor!